# PS4 External drive games not showing up after database rebuild [solved]

Tags: ps4, hard-drive

I heard I should rebuild the database on my PS4, so I did, while my external drive was plugged in.  Now, none of the games on that drive are in my games folder.  However, if I go to storage -> external drive -> applications, all the games are still on the disk.  Is there a way to access the games without manually reinstalling them all?

Edit: so, I unplugged the external drive and rebuilt the database, then plugged it in and waited turned it on.  After waiting for quite a while on the home page, my external drive games one by one gradually popped up.  I don't know if the second database rebuild was necessary and I just needed to wait, but issue is solved.

Comment: Are all of your external games digital? If you have at least a physical one, try inserting the discs and see if their icons show up.

Comment: Rather than posting your solution in the question, you should post it as a self-answer

Answer (score 1):

I unplugged the external drive and rebuilt the database, then plugged it in and waited turned it on. After waiting for quite a while on the home page, my external drive games one by one gradually popped up. I don't know if the second database rebuild was necessary and I just needed to wait, but issue is solved.

ps4
hard-drive